# Why tanh function return different in tensorflow and pytorch?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, activation-function

I find that `tensorflow` and `pytorch` `tanh` result is different, I want to know why did this happen?
I know that the difference is very small, so is this acceptable?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import torch

np.random.seed(123)
tf.random.set_seed(123)
torch.manual_seed(123)

batch, sentence_length, embedding_dim = 20, 5, 10
value = np.random.random((batch, sentence_length, embedding_dim)).astype("f")
value = value * 10

tf_x = tf.constant(value, dtype=tf.float32)
tf_out = tf.math.tanh(tf_x)

pt_x = torch.from_numpy(value)
pt_out = torch.tanh(pt_x)

print((tf_out.numpy() == pt_out.numpy()).all()) # return False
print(((tf_out.numpy() - pt_out.numpy()) < 1e-6).all()) # return True
```

- tensorflow == 2.5.0
- torch == 1.9.0

Comment: show the output please

Comment: @OldProgrammer output added

Comment: No show the value of tf_x and pt_x and the tf_out and pt_out

Comment: floating point values will never be exact

Comment: @OldProgrammer But when I test `Dense` in `tensorflow` and `Linear` in `PyTorch`, it is exactly same.

Answer (score 1):

Running your code with the following line at the end:

```
print(np.allclose(tf_out.numpy(), pt_out.numpy()))  # Returns True
```

You will receive `True`. I do not know exactly how tensorflow and pytorch compute the tanh oppeartion, but when working with floating points, you rarely are exactely equal. However, you should be receiving equal results up to a certain tolerance, which is exactly what `np.allclose()` checks. [Read more onallclose here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)